# LyX -- how to insert a dummy newline?

Tags: formatting, lyx

I have some Algorithmic sections, which are written externally in LaTeX and included as file includes in my LyX document. The algorithmic section renders with line breaks before and after, but appears inline in the LyX document. **Question**: Is there a way to insert dummy / editor-only line breaks in LyX? Analagous to the way one can write

```
hello
world
```

instead of

```
hello world
```

in LaTeX source, and the result will be the same.

I can't press "enter" or "ctrl+enter" (ragged line break, `\\`) before or after the figure, since that will create a new paragraph, which will be indented (I don't want this).

Below is a screenshot; the black section "procedure reduce_hla..." is the thing that I want editor-only newlines before and after.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl + Enter won't create a new paragraph and cause indentation. If you do start a new paragraph, you could edit the paragraph settings (right click in the paragraph) and set it to not be indented.

Comment: Surely the whole point of using LyX is that it is quasi-WISYWYG?

Comment: @Brent.Longborough, but, it isn't being WYSIWYM, the real LaTeX has line breaks around the algorithm, LyX doesn't.

Comment: You could add `\par` before and after the algorithm, and then remove any paragraph indentation by using `\noindent`. Does that work for you?

Comment: Somewhat related? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40447/adding-empty-lines-for-readability

Comment: Looks like a Lyx feature request to me