# LyX won't let me click on the new page + Won't allow blank lines

Tags: lyx

I am using LyX with MikTex (LaTeX) sorry if I destroy some of these terms.. I am new here..

When I want to create a new page, I click on Insert -> formatting -> new page.

But it won't let me write in that section.. I am very frustrated as I've just downloaded everything and the second it sets up - it does not work.. How can I fix this issue?

Plus, it does not let me do force blank lines.. what is the purpose of this IDE if you can't do whatever you want? I really don't know.. (I tried pressing enter, shift+enter, go to insert->formatting -> rigged line but nothing works)

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Do you have to use LyX? I have a feeling you won't like it. If you are set on using LyX, have you already read the Help > Introduction and Help > Tutorial? For blank space, you could try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152001/12212. For adding a new page, the idea is that you would type *after* that page break. Does that work?

Answer (score 1):

The problem of the new page I guess that is simply that you must  <kbd>→</kbd> to move the cursor after the new page line.

> what is the purpose of this IDE if you can't do whatever you want?

Error. The purpose  of this IDE (and LaTeX) is not that, but allow you to write documents in a *consistent* and elegant format.

If you edit your question and type something, you will note that added extra spaces  and extra blank lines are ignored in the output. This is to maintain a consistent page layout of the web page.
LyX act similarly, but instead of ignoring your wrong decision at the output, ignore the input, to teach you that is wrong ...

1. Add more than one space between words.
2. force blank lines between paragraphs.
3. Indent (or not indent) manually a paragraph.
4. Put the authors before of the title.
5. etc.

Some  of these actions are often careless mistakes  when typing, or worse, naive attempts to control  document layout like in a typewriter of the XIX century. LyX help in the first case, reverting the mistakes, and in the second case teach you that what you are trying is a job for LaTeX,  not for the user.

This mean that you cannot change the layout? Not at all. For instance, You can fix the spaces among all paragraphs automatically, and you can add some vertical spacers manually, but not accidentally as pressing Enter twice by error.